# Keep seeing TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float

Tags: python, regression, typeerror

I am relatively new to using Python, I am trying to run a regression with a merged dataset and it keeps showing me the error "TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float". I do not know what it means or how to fix it. Anything Helps!!!

Here is my code

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

fit = ols('Congregations ~ ViolentCrime ', data=data).fit() 

print(fit.summary())
print(fit.params)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(data['ViolentCrime'], data['Congregations'], 'ro')
plt.plot(data['ViolentCrime'], fit.params.focal_year*data['ViolentCrime'] + fit.params.Intercept)
plt.ylabel('Congregations')
plt.xlabel('ViolentCrime')
```

[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tPhm.png)

Comment: There must by more to the error that you're not telling us. See how to create a [mcve] and edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

plt.plot considers its first two positional arguments to be a labels of x and y axes.

> Plotting labelled data
>
> There's a convenient way for plotting objects with labelled data (i.e. data that can be accessed by index obj['y']). Instead of giving the data in x and y, you can provide the object in the data parameter and just give the labels for x and y:
>
> >>> plot('xlabel', 'ylabel', data=obj)
>
> All indexable objects are supported. > This could e.g. be a dict, a pandas.DataFrame or a structured numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the error. Even after removing all commas and periods on my excel sheet, excel was automatically adding commas in the thousands. I found out how to remove them and it worked.
I Ctl+A selected all the cells, then right clicked, selected Format Cells, go under the tab 'Number', and unselected the box 'Use 1000 separator (,)'

Comment: Please consider to add more details in your answer if it just belongs to your own question. You perfectly explained the reason you found why Excel was causing the issue but omitted the details on how did you actually changed that option to solve the problem. It could be helpful to anyone that will happen to visit your answer in the future. Thank you for listening my fair suggestion.

Comment: I added the specifics of my solution. Thank you for the suggestion